# Fastest way to get minimum elements in a list less than a particular element

Tags: python, list, sum, python-2.x, minimum

I am better off explaining with an example
Suppose, I have a list [6,3,5,1,4,2].

Starting from index 0, find all items that are smaller (that have not been marked) than the value at that index.

```
Index 0: [6,3,5,1,4,2]  
Elements less than 6: 5{3,5,1,4,2} 
Visited array: [1 0 0 0 0 0]

Index 1: [6,3,5,1,4,2]  
Elements less than 3: 2 {1,2}
Visited array: [1 1 0 0 0 0]

Index 2: [6,3,5,1,4,2]  
Elements less than 5: 3 {1,4,2}
Visited array: [1 1 1 0 0 0]

Index 3: [6,3,5,1,4,2]  
Elements less than 1: 0 {NULL}
Visited array: [1 1 1 1 0 0]

Index 4: [6,3,5,1,4,2]  
Elements less than 4: 1 {2}
Visited array: [1 1 1 1 1 0]

This yields an array as [5 2 3 0 1 0]
```

Currently using,

```
def get_diff(lis):
    ans=[]
    for index,elem in enumerate(lis):
        number_of_smaller=len(filter(lambda x:x<elem ,lis[index+1:]))
        ans.append(number_of_smaller)
    return ans
```

However, I have a feeling that this will not be efficient. How do I make it worthy of a huge list? Do I smell prefix sums?. Thanks,

Comment: *However, I have a feeling that this will not be efficient.* what makes you feel that? Did you test it?

Comment: Yes, a list of length 10**4 will easily laugh at my code. The current code, though pythonic in my opinion isn't fast enough

Comment: Your algorithm has complexity O(n²). If you want to make your code faster, you need to use a different algorithm.
(I have a solution but this margin is too small for me to write it.)

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use a list comprehension within a dict comprehension to preserve the item as the key and the items which are less than it as the value (and use `collections.OrderedDict` to preserve the order):

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> def get_diff(lis):
...        return OrderedDict((item,[i for i in lis if i<item]) for item in lis)
```

Since your condition is `<` there is no need to exclude the item itself, because that the cost of removing it in comparison is greater than including it.

Also if you want to preserve the indices to you can use `enumerate` to loop over your list :

```
def get_diff(lis):
       return OrderedDict((item,index),[i for i in lis if i<item]) for index,item in enumerate(lis))
```

And if you want to count the number of that items you can use a generator expression within `sum` function :

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> def get_diff(lis):
...        return OrderedDict((item,sum(1 for i in lis if i<item)) for item in lis)
```

NOTE: if you want to count the item less than any item after that (with larger index) you can simply use a indexing in your loop :

```
>>> def get_diff(lis):
...        return OrderedDict((item,sum(1 for i in lis[index:] if i<item)) for index,item in enumerate(lis))
... 
>>> get_diff(l).values()
[5, 2, 3, 0, 1, 0]
```

Comment: Incorrect. He wants to count from the elements behind it.

Comment: @hsfzxjy I don't think so, he didn't mentioned that!

Comment: @hsfzxjy Yep, I see the expected result now, fixed!

Answer (score -1):

```
my_list = [6,3,5,1,4,2] 

def get_diff(lis):
    result = []
    for visited, i in enumerate(range(len(lis))):
        limit = lis[i]
        elem = filter(None, [x if x < limit else None for x in lis][visited + 1:])
        result.append(len(elem))
    return result

print get_diff(my_list)
#[5, 2, 3, 0, 1, 0]
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. However, this is brute force too and I am looking for an algorithm that uses prefix sum techniques, AVL etc to optimize lookups